# Compare the growth rate of functions $f(n)=(2^{n+1}-1)^{1/\log n}$ and $n^{\log n}$

Tags: functional-analysis, limits, functions, logarithms

How do I compare the growth rate of functions $f(n)=(2^{n+1}-1)^{1/\log n}$ and $g(n)=n^{\log n}$

**My Attempt**

\begin{align}
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\log f(n)}{\log g(n)}&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\log\Big(2^{n+1}-1\Big)^{1/\log n}}{\log 2^{(\log n)^2}}\\
&\approx\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\frac{1}{\log n}\log\big(2^{n+1}\big)}{{(\log n)^2}}\quad\Bigg[2^{n+1}-1=2^{n+1}\text{ for large }n\\
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n+1}{(\log n)^3}\\
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{3(\log n)^2.\frac{1}{n\ln 2}}\bigg[\text{Applying L'Hospital rule}\\
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n\ln 2}{3(\log n)^2}\\
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\ln 2}{6(\log n).\frac{1}{n\ln 2}}\\
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{(\ln 2)^2.n}{6\log n}=\infty\\
\end{align}

But when I tried to plot the graphs in Mathematica I am getting $g(n)$ to be larger than $f(n)$:

[image: pic]

**Note:** $\log n=\log_2 n$ and $\ln 2=\log_e 2$

**Mathematica code:** $\text{Plot}\left[\left\{f(n)=\left(2^{n+1}-1\right)^{\frac{1}{\log _2(n)}},g(n)=n^{\log _2(n)}\right\},\{n,0,10\},\text{PlotLabels}\to \text{Expressions},\text{ImageSize}\to \text{Large}\right]$

Comment: Your calculations should have stopped at $\frac{(n+1)\log 2}{\log^3 n}$, and any fixed power of $\log n$ grows more slowly than $n$.

Comment: @AnneBauval $\frac{d}{dn}(\log n)^3=3(\log n)^2.\frac{d}{dn}\log n=3(\log n)^2.\frac{1}{n\ln 2}$ right? where $\log n=\log_2 n$ and $\ln 2=\log_e 2$

Comment: 1) "But when I tried to plot the graphs in Mathematica I am getting f(x)
 to be larger than g(x)": you mean smaller, not larger 2) The note $\log=\log_2$ is useful but $\ln=\log_e$ is useless. 3) I agree with abiessu

Comment: @AnneBauval I have added the mathematica code I used in the post. please check

Comment: @AnneBauval Srry I got confused with your statement "But when I tried to plot the graphs in Mathematica I am getting f(x) to be larger than g(x)" in the previous comment.

Comment: @AnneBauval Srry it was a typo, fixed it. Do you think the contradiction has something to do with taking the $\log$ of the functions in the limit ?

Comment: The graph makes sense, because $x$ overtakes $\log^3(x)$ only around 1000. You just aren't plotting far enough.

Comment: As wrote CommandMaster, you may try logarithmic scale on axes)

Comment: He was right, it sufficed to plot farther! https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=log+plot+%282%5E%7Bx%2B1%7D-1%29%5E%7B1%2F%5Clog+x%7D%2Cx%5E%7B%5Clog+x%7D%2C+x%3D0+to+500

Comment: @CommandMaster Okay thanks. That makes sense.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it was answered by a comment.